# What does VisualStudio do when it sends a `textDocument.documentSymbol` request to a language server?

Tags: visual-studio, language-server-protocol

I implemented a language server and got it to work with Visual Studio 2022 17.5.2. The server sends a request with method `textDocument/documentSymbol`. However I can not tell how the response to this request is used. What is the purpose of this request and how can I see the result in Visual Studio?

Comment: Did you find any hint on what it is used for? I have the exact same question. Is it just a waste of send bytes?

Comment: @HJLebbink no, but in my opinion VisualStudioCode is the better software to test language servers. Maybe you can figure it out there.